# Vue 3 Passing Additional Data as a Parameter with Object Syntax Dynamic Events

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events, dynamic, event-handling

Is there a way to pass additional data to event handlers when using the object structure syntax?

Example:

MySFC.vue:

```
<template>
   <template v-for="action in actions" : key="action.id">
       <button v-on="action.eventHandlers"> <!--Looking for some way to pass both event and additional data here-->
           {{ action.name }}
       </button>
   </template>
</template>
<script>

    import { actions } from '@/lib/my-actions.js';

    export default {
        setup(props, ctx){           
            return{
                actions,
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

my-actions.js:

```
export const actions = {
    name: 'my action',
    eventHandlers: {
        click: (event, myData) => {
            console.log(myData);       
        },
        mousedown: (event, myData) => {
            console.log(myData);
        }
    }
}
```

Normally if you have a specific event you are trying to handle you can just do something like:

```
<button @click="myClickHandler($event, myData)"> </button>
```

But in this case I am trying to build a wrapper of sorts for plugins and do not know what events may need to be handled, so I can't pre-define with v-on which events to look for.

I saw some options for attaching dynamic events, but I only see examples where the event itself is passed, not with additional parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to bind the function's initial arguments. This can only be done with regular functions (not arrow functions).

```js
// @/lib/my-actions.js
const myClickData = {
  id: 'my click data',
}
const myMouseDownData = {
  id: 'my mousedown data',
}

export const actions = [
  {
    name: 'my action',
    eventHandlers: {
      click: function (myData, event) {
        console.log('click', { event, myData })
      }.bind(undefined, myClickData),

      mousedown: function (myData, event) {
        console.log('mousedown', { event, myData })
      }.bind(undefined, myMouseDownData),
    },
  },
]
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-bind-function-args?file=src/lib/my-actions.js)

Comment: spent this morning testing this out, when in the same file it seems to work but when i split them in 2 files it still returns undefined

Comment: Can you share a link to a reproduction?